# Issue with NSDateFormetter iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdateformatter

just figured out that NSDateFormatter stopped recognising AM/PM with 24 hour format. My code is

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy MM dd HH:mma";

NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015 02 11 12:30PM"];
NSLog(@"%@", date1);
NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015 02 11 13:30PM"];
NSLog(@"%@", date2);
```

The output I got was showing same date is:

```
2015-12-24 15:38:54.234 xyz[580:88238] 2015-02-11 07:00:00 +0000
2015-12-24 15:38:54.235 xyz[580:88238] 2015-02-11 07:00:00 +0000
```

But earlier it's working before i updated my XCode to 7.2 and my iPod to 9.2. Please let me know if it's an iOS 9.2 bug.

Comment: Please try to use small "h" means "hh:mma" beause for 12 hour formate small "h" used and "H" used for  24  hour formate.

Comment: 13:30PM doesn't exists! am-pm is 12 hours format!  
Besides, when you're logging NSDate, it will log with GMT+0 timezone.

Comment: Please first correct your question as @arturdev says: 13:30PM doesn't exists!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`13:30PM` does not make sense. Either use the 24 hour clock *or* `AM`/`PM`.

In particular `13:30 PM` is not a valid time when using the 24 hour clock.

**Solution:** remove the `PM` and remove the `a` from the date formatter.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy MM dd HH:mm";

NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015 02 11 12:30"];
NSLog(@"%@", date1);
NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015 02 11 13:30"];
NSLog(@"%@", date2);
```

Correctly outputs

> 2015-12-24 11:42:43.420 Flip[3080:312362] 2015-02-11 11:30:00 +0000
>   2015-12-24 11:42:43.422 Flip[3080:312362] 2015-02-11 12:30:00 +0000

(the timezone difference causes an offset of one houer here)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
  NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];

  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd  MM  YY HH:mma"];

  NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];

  NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use hh:mma for 12 hr format or use HH:mm for 24 hr format

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy MM dd hh:mma";

NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015 02 11 12:30PM"];
NSLog(@"Date1: %@", date1);
NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015 02 11 01:30PM"];
NSLog(@"Date2: %@", date2);

NSString *str1 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date1];
NSString *str2 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date2];
NSLog(@"DateStr1: %@", str1);
NSLog(@"DateSTr2: %@", str2);
```

Output:-

```
Date1: 2015-02-11 07:00:00 +0000
Date2: 2015-02-11 08:00:00 +0000
DateStr1: 2015 02 11 12:30PM
DateSTr2: 2015 02 11 01:30PM
```